# Topological current in (2+1)D spinorial electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, dirac-equation, higgs

Giving the coupled Dirac equations for $\psi$ and its conjugate $\bar{\psi}$ in 2+1:
\begin{align}
(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi&=qA_\mu\gamma^\mu\psi,\\
\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu+m)&=-qA_\mu\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu,
\end{align}
where $\gamma^\mu$ are the 2+1 gamma matrices in the reducible representations composed by the two irreducible inequivalent representations and the conserved currente:
\begin{equation}
J^\mu=q\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi.
\end{equation}
Accordingly to this paper: [semenoff](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.53.2449).
we can find an induced current:
\begin{equation}
J^\mu=\dfrac{q}{8\pi}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}F_{\nu\lambda}(x) \mathrm{sgn}(m)+\cdots
\end{equation}
where $F_{\nu\lambda}$ is the Faraday tensor, but it doesn't explains how to get this current from the equations. Accordingly to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics) in 2+1 scalar electrodynamics there is a topological current related to Higgs-mechanism, the current has the same shape:
\begin{equation}
J^\mu_{\mathrm{top}}=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}F_{\nu\lambda}(x),
\end{equation}
which was shown by Nielsen and Olesen in 1973: [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321373903507?via%3Dihub). This makes sense since it matches with the Hodge Dual $^*F^\mu=\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}F_{\nu\lambda}/2$ and the maxwell equation $\partial_\mu {^*F^\mu}=0$. But I couldn't find this result in the paper.

Someone has an idea of how to get this current from the Dirac equations?